# Detailed references on Quantum Principal Component Analysis

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, resource-request, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I am looking for review articles and other online resources on qPCA based on Lloyd's [original proposal](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys3029). I have found the original source to be slightly hand-wavy with the details so I am having trouble filling in some gaps. In particular with regard to how the algorithm can even be implemented, say, using a program. Can someone help me finding sources to help me understand the work better? I am aware of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.00778) as a result of [an answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29600/21263) to an earlier question. Are there any others?

Comment: Not sure this is what you are looking for but I put an implementation [here](https://github.com/qcc4cp/qcc/blob/main/src/quantum_pca.py).

Comment: Maybe also this https://scirate.com/arxiv/2302.14324

Answer (score 0):

You may look at "Quantum Algorithm Implementations for Beginners" (ACM Transactions on Quantum Computing, Vol. 3, No. 4, Article 18) by Abhijith et al., p.59. Link: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3517340

Comment: I have, but it is specific to an implementation on a 5-qubit machine. I would like to see a reference implementing the algorithm using the exponential swap gates as well.