# The necessity of a qRAM-based state preparation in qSVT-type problems

Tags: quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, state-preparation, quantum-memory, quantum-inspired

I've been reading a couple of papers regarding [qPCA](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3029) and its [dequantisation](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.060503). In the course of my reading, it appears to me that one of the ingredients that makes this dequantisation meaningful is the requirement for a qRAM for state preparation when it comes to using qPCA for analysing classical datasets. The other ingredient being that the problem in question is low-dimensional. While one potential way to avoid dequantisation is tackling a high dimensional problem, the other seems to be removing qRAM from the picture. In light of [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29600/21263) in an older question of mine, I wonder if this so-called *quantum data* that is sampled directly from a physical system requires a qRAM or any state preparation. In summary, my question is as follows -

Can quantum computation (in particular qSVT-type problems) be done without a qRAM-based state preparation? If so, are there any caveats?